# Biztalk Pipeline Issue - EDI Classification Failure

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2016

I am running into an issue with a BizTalk project that I am creating to turn system XML into an EDI document. There error that I am getting is:

**There was a failure executing the send pipeline:**

> "Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.DefaultPipelines.EdiSend, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "EDI Assembler" Send Port: "PRX_SureCost_Out" URI: "C:\Users\rubyhaus\Desktop\SCA-EDI\%MessageID%.x12" Reason: A message was encountered with root element name of purchaseOrderResponse. It could not be classified as an X12 or Edifact message. The root namespace was

From all my investigation, it seems that either my XML is not being mapped which I have setup up from the receive port to move from a internal XML output to a standard `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006#X12_00401_855` or it has something to do with my agreement not resolving properly. I been trying to resolve for the past two days and have not been able to find a reason.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Did the root namespace in the error message match your internal XML?

Comment: The was no root namespace provided. They error message ended without saying.

Comment: So what namespace is on the XML you expect to be mapped?

Comment: The namespace is PRXEDI and the Type is PRX_messaging_180527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because PurchaseOrderResponse is not being mapped to the 855 Schema.

If you have configured a Map on the Receive Port, most likely, you are not running the XmlDisassembler, such as in the XmlReceive Pipeline.

The XmlDisassembler id what 'types' the message so it can re resolved by other components such as Port Maps.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I had been using a PassThroughPipeline and that was not allowing the type identification to trigger the map.